# Get 59 from 1,9,4,8 in order

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

I’m stuck on trying get $59$ by the numbers $1,9,4,8$ in order. I have no idea if it’s possible, I made it for 1-70 just not 59.

I made it without order: $(-1+8)*9-4$

You can use not only the basic math operators, I tried factorial, powers, square roots, logs, even binomial coefficient but that we read it from top to down.

I would like for help from anyone, maybe a solution with an operator I didn’t think of.

By the way, do you think it’s possible for someone to write a program that we give couple numbers, and ask to get other number, with or not order?

EDIT: I guess there can be some solution, but in my opinion using a function symbol, or the floor function, is cheating. 
The solutions I liked and I don't think we need anymore:

> $-1 + ( (\sqrt{9})!)! / (4 + 8)$ and $-1 + ( (\sqrt{9})! )!! + 4 + 8$ by [@ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12062/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) 
>  
>  $-1 + \sqrt{9}! * (\sqrt{4} + 8)$ by [@Keelhaul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43465/keelhaul)

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE. How do you know for sure such a solution exists? Where did you get this puzzle from?

Comment: Hey, I have no idea if there is an answer. That’s why I came here, because maybe someone will have a nice solution. We got a “mission” from our math teacher to find this answers for 1-70 with the numbers 1,9,4,8 by order. I got stuck only on 59.

Comment: Then this must be related to what your math teacher is teaching you at the moment, right? They wouldn't expect you to use an esoteric operator that you are not supposed to know.

Comment: No no, our country celebrates 70 years, and it started in 1948. Tbh, I don’t even learn math in school because I learn in the university. But my friends asked for my help because the teacher is giving 5 points bonus to the recent test.

Comment: So, this technically is a question for a school test.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a test, more a class challenge.

Comment: The teacher is giving bonuspoints to a test, to those who can google this question. It is in my opinion the same as an ongoing competition. Those who google well or ask others to solve their puzzles, get points.

Comment: Unfortunately answers are no longer possible. If squares are really allowed, what about -1*(9-4)+8²

Comment: @puck My bad, I meant square roots. I edited it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should work :

> $-1 + \sqrt{9}! * (\sqrt{4} + 8)$

Comment: Hey, how do you find this answer? I can't even think how do you think like that?

Comment: In the most cases I’m trying to solve this type of questions, I’m looking for familiar numbers close to the target. Then I tey to reach them. But most of the time for me is just keep playing with the numbers until I find it. This is my way though, I don’t know how others do it.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson It looks like Keelhaul tried to get to 60 and subtract 1. This leaves you with 9, 4 and 8 to get to 60, which is way easier. Then making 10 out of sqrt(4) + 8 only leaves you with the problem of getting a 6 from a 9. Pretty good algorithm!

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson, this is because  You are the Most Stupid Person :p. More seriously, Ian pretty much said it : I tried getting to 60 with 9 4 8, knowing that 9 could become 3 with the root squaring or 6 with the factorial of the root squaring, and 4 could easily become 2 as well.

Answer (score 7):

How about

> $(1\times9) + \lfloor 4^{\sqrt8}\rfloor$

Comment: So what is the result of Sqrt(8)?

Comment: Irrational AFAIK.  It's $2\sqrt2$ or approximately 2.8284...

Comment: I know, so basically your answer is an approximation?

Comment: Sneaky use of floor(n) a.k.a. $ \lfloor n \rfloor $   (or should that be sneaky use of powers?)

Comment: @AlexHajnal I agree that using floor is kind of cheating, but what do you mean about sneaky use of powers?

Comment: Using a non-integer power

Answer (score 3):

> $ 1 - \varphi(9) + \varphi(4!)\times8$

Using the special function:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: Original, but feels like cheating

Comment: Same as @Mixxiphoid, I think it is cheating using a function where you just use the letter that symbols it. If you wrote the definition of a function it was nice, but then you repeat numbers, as I read about the definition.

Comment: Mind you, the same could be said for (double) factorials (or square roots for that matter)

Comment: Since binomial coefficient was mentioned in the question i figured it was not a problem. But I do agree that this was probably not the solution that was thought of originally and a simpler solution was in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Another one, based on Keelhaul's idea:

> $-1 + ( (\sqrt{9})!)! / (4 + 8)$

And one more that uses the double factorial:

> $-1 + ( (\sqrt{9})! )!! + 4 + 8$

Comment: Wow! I like the first solution. 
I tried using double factorial, but isn't your second solution wrong? 3!!=1*3=3, then -1+3+4+8=14. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oops, my bad, missed another factorial! Should be $6!! = 2*4*6 = 48$ and you need a standard factorial to get 6.